# Badges for a total number of answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, badge-request

There are badges which you can receive for voting on questions/answers (Supporter, Civic Duty and Electorate) which are not hard to get when you are patient, because they do not require outside action (except that others have to post questions/answers). How about creating a similar set of badges which someone could receive for a total number of posted answers (for example with non-negative or positive score). I understand that answering the question isn't a hard action (voting is even easier), so the limits to acquire these badges would be probably around several hundreds or thousands.

Answer (score 10):

I would not want to see people gaming to try and get this badge.  There are already badges for posting *good* answers.  I think this is preferable, since it rewards quality, not quantity.

Comment: That's true, but the same problem is with badges for voting on questions/answers. When a person without patience wants to receive them there is nothing to stop him from voting whatever, even "bad" answers. You can at least flag or moderate answers, but you can do nothing about voting.

Comment: @yojimbo87: There are ways to game voting and we try to deal with those both algorithmically and through moderation.  But your comment seems to be arguing that because we have a problem with voting, we should also introduce the same problem for answering.

Comment: It wasn't meant that bad, I was just thinking that if badges for voting are still fine in spite of "game mechanics" then answers shouldn't be a problem. There is also motivation in it for new user to start answering questions and take part in community. False answers won't take anyone far.